# Is HP Envy TouchSmart 4-1210sg notebook compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, hp, compatibility

Is my Hewlett Packard Envy TouchSmart 4-1210sg notebook compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should verify that all necessary devices work under Ubuntu: network/wireless card, bluetooth, sound devices. Also whether there is graphical latency.

Comment: You can make a bootable USB and test your device with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your computer has an 1.8 GHz Intel Core i5 processor and 8 GB of RAM.  In other words, it's a newer laptop with lots of power.  Sure it should work!  If you want to be sure, download Ubuntu to a USB thumb drive, and then boot your notebook from the thumb drive to try out Ubuntu without changing anything on your hard drive.  Then if you want to continue, there will be a desktop icon on your temporary Ubuntu installation to install Ubuntu on the hard drive.  You can have both Ubuntu and Windows installed on the hard drive at the same time, dual-boot style.  Go ahead, try it out, you have nothing to lose but disk space.